# how does IConvertible works

Tags: c#, iconvertible

I have the following code which I got from the internet. I am not sure about the use of `IConvertible`. MSDN says:

> "This interface provides methods to convert the value of an instance of an implementing type to a common language runtime type that has an equivalent value."

Is it meant that, I can assign anything to `IConvertible` and while using it converts it to the implementing type?

For example, in below example I pass parameters as key-value pair where key is `string` and value is `IConvertible`.

```
SqlParameter object = new SqlParameter(param.Key, param.Value)
```

`SqlParameter object` takes key as `string` and value as depending on the type declared in the table or stored procedure. How does it exactly works here?

```
private SqlCommand GetCommand(string procedureName,   
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IConvertible>> parameters)
{
  foreach (var param in parameters)
  {
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(param.Key, param.Value));
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean how does passing **common language runtime types** as `IConvertible` work?

Comment: i wanted to know, how does here "new SqlParameter(param.Key, param.Value));", the value gets converted to the specified type that the stored procedure expects